# Stopping Jquery Animation from running twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to make this animation to stop after running the first time, but If I add the .stop(true) won't work..any ideas??

Here is my jQuery.

```
function doDisplayError(){  
    $("#errors").animate (
            { 'top': '200px' }, {
                duration: '300',
                easing: 'easeOutQuad'
            }).delay(3000).animate (
            { 'top': '-200px' }, {
                duration: '200',
                easing: 'easeInBack'
            });
}
```

Comment: Set a if and a run_once variable to check?

Comment: Why is it running twice in the first place? Is the function being called twice for some reason?

Comment: On what event are you running the animation? if you are running the animation on mouse event of an element, this can be a event bubling problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to determine if execution has occurred similar to this:

```
var animationExecuted = false;

function doDisplayError() {
    if(animationExecuted){
        return false;
    };
    console.log("executed");
    animationExecuted = true;

    $("#errors").animate({
        'top': '200px'
    }, {
        duration: '300',
        easing: 'easeOutQuad'
    }).delay(3000).animate({
        'top': '-200px'
    }, {
        duration: '200',
        easing: 'easeInBack'
    });
}​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvF5w/) - Only execute code once

However, it might a be better to see why it is executed more than once and if possible address that issue instead of compensating for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
error_run_once=0;
function doDisplayError(){  
    if (error_run_once=0){
        $("#errors").animate (
            { 'top': '200px' }, {
               duration: '300',
               easing: 'easeOutQuad'
            }).delay(3000).animate (
           { 'top': '-200px' }, {
               duration: '200',
               easing: 'easeInBack'
            });
        error_run_once = 1;
    } else{
       // what else you want to do if you don't show animation?
    }
}
```

see if it works..
== edit ==

And, like the other commented, the better way may be to not call it a second time at all. Modify how it is called could be a better way.